Kronecker tensor product preserving operations
Suppose I have two tensors, of order $m$
$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^p u_i \otimes \cdots \otimes u_i, \qquad B = \sum_{i=1}^p v_i\otimes \cdots \otimes v_i.
$$
What are the class of transformations $T(u_i) = v_i$ such that $A = B$ is preserved?
For $m = 2$ it's orthogonal rotations, e.g. $V = UQ$ for some orthonormal matrix $Q$, and
$V = [v_1,...,v_p]$, $U = [u_1,...,u_p]$. Is there an easy way to generalize this intuition to higher dimensions?
Thanks!
